# Sencha Touch Carousel and TabPanel

Tags: extjs, carousel, tabpanel

I want to have a view with a TabPanel and inside a Carousel with two cards.

Like this:

```
var view = Ext.define("abril16.view.Main2", {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
requires: ['Ext.TitleBar', 'Ext.carousel.Carousel'],
config: {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom', 
    items: [{
        title: 'Home',
        iconCls: 'home',
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        scrollable: true,
        layout: 'fit',
        flex: 1,
        items: {
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Beetoom',
        },
    },
    {
        title: 'Discover',
        iconCls: 'action',
        scrollable: true,
        items: [{
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Select',
            layout: 'fit',
            flex: 1,
        }, 
        {
            docked: 'top',
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Discover',
        },
        {
            xtype: 'carousel',
            items: [{   
                            xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                            name: 'Hola',
                            label: 'Hola'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                            name: 'Action',
                            label: 'Adventure'
                        }
                    ]
                }

                ]
    }
        ]
    }

            });
```

The problem is that nothing happens here. There are no syntax errors, but there is no layout displayed and instead the carousel I have a blank background inside the panel.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code. Here's what I have observed from your code.

1. Why you require two titlebars `['Select','Discover']` in your second tab of `'Discover'`. I think, you added titlebar two times in your `'Discover'` tab.  It absolutely makes no sense to have two titlebars for the same tab.
2. Include the Discover tab code like this,

   ```
    {
           title: 'Discover',
           iconCls: 'action',
           styleHtmlContent:true,
           layout:'card',
           items: [
               {
                   docked: 'top',
                   xtype: 'titlebar',
                   title: 'Discover',
               },
               {
               xtype: 'carousel',
               items: [
                   {   
                     xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                     name: 'Hola',
                     label: 'Hola'     
                   },
                   {
                      xtype:'checkboxfield',
                      name:'Action',
                      label:'Adventure'    
                   }
                ]
             }
           ]
    }
   ```